# Which version of ctags had the `-T` option?

Tags: linux, command-line, ctags

I am looking at an old `Makefile` which specifies the `-T` option to `ctags`. I am running exuberant ctags 5.9, and it does not have the `-T` option.

A web search for the term `ctags -T option` did not reveal anything.

Does anyone know which version of `ctags` supported the `-T` option and what it means?

Comment: could it be an error in the Makefile? maybe they intended -t?

Comment: @Clayton, The commit is from more than 2 years ago, so I would have assumed it would have been discovered and fixed earlier if it was wrong? I mean it could still be wrong.

Comment: I don't know much about C but it looks like when they migrated to GitHub they were able to transfer over the commit/revision history but maybe you can poke around here and find it? https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags ..wish I had a better answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, on my Gentoo system I have this:

```
$ ctags --help | grep -e -T
-T, --typedefs-and-c++

$ ctags --version          
ctags (GNU Emacs 24.5)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is distributed under the terms in ETAGS.README

$ readlink $(which ctags) 
ctags-emacs-24

$ equery belongs $(which ctags)
app-editors/emacs-24.5 (/usr/bin/ctags-emacs-24)

$ eselect ctags list
Available ctags symlink targets:
  [1]   ctags-emacs-24 *
  [2]   exuberant-ctags
```

`ctags-emacs-24` is ctags [implementation](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-test/BuildTags) from emacs package, while [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) are available through `exuberant-ctags` command.

I guess on your system, `ctags` command is exuberant ctags, which doesn't have `-T` option.

Comment: Can you also give either `ctags -V` or `ctags --version` for completeness?